# pageY on div with overflow-y

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a script that detects where your mouse enters on hover.

I'm trying to use the script within a div with

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

The script uses pageY which detects position relative to the window, is there a way I could have pageY detect the position relative to the containing div?

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9r7M/38/

Comment: Have you tried domelement.scrollTop?

Comment: Is that the complete script in fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, the issue I run into is that when I hover over the li's in that are visible on load, the script registers where the position the mouse enters, but as you scroll down, it only registers the entry from the top.

Comment: Perhaps you can compare `pageY` with the position of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do on your jsfiddle example as you didn't explain that. But just to answer your question, you just need to subtract the mouse position (`pageX` & `pageY`) to the containing `<div>`'s `offset()` position then add the `<div>` scroll position (`scrollTop()` & `scrollLeft()`).

```
$('div').mousemove(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left + $(this).scrollLeft();
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top + $(this).scrollTop();
});
```

Check this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TS6bK/1/).