# While using custom hover image effect, when another html element is added to body, the picture's orientation changes on hover

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

I use this effect from here:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/03/12/image-distortion-effects-with-svg-filters/

https://codepen.io/furkanyildiz/pen/bGwebmR

```
    <div style="height:5rem;">
this div disrupts the render location of images </div>
<main>
  <div class="content">
    <svg class="distort" width="350" height="450" viewBox="0 0 350 450">
      <filter id="distortionFilter">
        <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.07 0.01" numOctaves="5" seed="2" stitchTiles="stitch" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="noise" />
        <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="0" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
      </filter>
      <g filter="url(#distortionFilter)">
        <image class="distort__img" x="50" y="50" xlink:href="img/1.jpg" height="350" width="250" />
        <image class="distort__img" x="50" y="50" xlink:href="img/2.jpg" height="350" width="250" />
        <image class="distort__img" x="50" y="50" xlink:href="img/3.jpg" height="350" width="250" />
        <image class="distort__img" x="50" y="50" xlink:href="img/4.jpg" height="350" width="250" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="menu__link">Shanghai</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu__link">Taipei</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu__link">Bangkok</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu__link">Kyoto</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</main>
```

What i want to achive is:

Regardless of the page size, I want the image to appear in the middle of the mouse pointer when hovering over the menu item,
The coordinate in which the picture will appear is adjusted according to the page size in js codes.

I just want it to adjust according to the .content class in itself instead.
As the size of the page decreases, the orientation of the picture changes.
please help.

Comment: You should give attribution to [where you're copying your code from](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/03/12/image-distortion-effects-with-svg-filters/), fix all errors and warnings in the console before expecting us to help, and [upgrade to GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3-migration/). As for your question, you just need to compensate by adding the container's offset position to the position calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, i take your advise and added link where i copied code from and fix the console errors on codepen, but i didnt get the result i want still, can you help me little more, when page height is changed (by adding other elements) image render position is changing. I'm not expert on js and couldn't fix the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:
Effect that I'm trying to run is using pageY and pageX read-only properties.
When I add another element to the page while using this effect, page height is changing of course. "pageY" value is changing too.

pageY which detects position relative to the window, with the following codes pageY detect the position relative to the containing div.

```
  this.targetY = pageY - document.querySelector('.myDiv').offsetTop - document.querySelector('html').scrollTop;
```

We simply extract offsetTop and scrolled pixel count from pageY value.

[I reached the solution from the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928711/14509028)